# Directshow VC++ express 2010 vs Graph Edit

Tags: c++, directshow

I have a program that creates a directshow graph for capture of video from a hardware device and direct encoding into mpeg-4 format.

I had originally ran this code on another machine, where it worked.  Now that I have switched machines, the code has the behaviour below:

What works:
   The graph is set up correctly
   ALL FILES ARE CREATED
   There are no errors in creating the graph
   I use IMediaControl::Start and ::Stop
   The issue occurs for XVID, ffdshow, divx encoders and haali matroska, matroska, and gdcl muxers

The issue:
    When I run the program in VC++ 2010 express, the file remains static and gains no content. However, when I run the graph using Graph Edit, the file increases in size.

Any ideas (settings, maybe?) on what might be different between the machines?  Or why the graph runs properly in GraphEdit but not in VC++ 2010 Express?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do something wrong. You should show some code. A typical reason would be your NOT dispatching window messages on filter graph management/wait thread.